# Obtaining keys and values from JSON nested array in nest

Tags: arrays, json, database, python-3.x

First time posting! I am converting JSON data (dictionary) from a server into a csv file. The keys and values taken are fine apart from the nest "Astronauts", which is an array. Basically every individual JSON string is a datum that may contains from 0 to an unlimited number of astronauts which features I would like to extract as independent values. For instance something like this:

- Astronaut1_Spaceships_First: Katabom
- Astronaut1_Spaceships_Second: The Kraken
- Astronaut1_name: Jebeddia
- (...)
- Astronaut2_gender: Hopefully female

and so on. The problem here is that the nest is set as an array and not a dictionary so I do not know what to do. I have tried the dpath library as well as flattering the nest but nothing did change. Any ideas?

```
import json
import os
import csv
import datetime
import dpath.util #Dpath library needs to be installed first

datum = {"Mission": "Make Earth Greater Again", "Objective": "Prove Earth is flat", "Astronauts": [{"Spaceships": {"First": "Katabom", "Second": "The Kraken"}, "Name": "Jebeddiah", "Gender": "Hopefully male", "Age": 35, "Prefered colleages": [], "Following missions": [{"Payment_status": "TO BE CONFIRMED"}]}, {"Spaceships": {"First": "The Kraken", "Second": "Minnus I"}, "Name": "Bob", "Gender": "Hopefully female", "Age": 23, "Prefered colleages": [], "Following missions": [{"Payment_status": "TO BE CONFIRMED"}]}]}

#Parsing process
        parsed = json.loads(datum)  #datum is the JSON string retrieved from the server

def flattenjson(parsed, delim):
    val = {}
    for i in parsed.keys():
        if isinstance(parsed[i], dict):
            get = flattenjson(parsed[i], delim)
            for j in get.keys():
                val[i + delim + j] = get[j]
        else:
        val[i] = parsed[i]

    return val
flattened = flattenjson(parsed,"__")

#process of creating csv file
keys=['Astronaut1_Spaceship_First','Astronaut2_Spaceship_Second', 'Astronaut1_Name]  #reduced to 3 keys for this example

 writer = csv.DictWriter(OD, keys ,restval='Null', delimiter=",", quotechar="\"", quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL, dialect= "excel")
        writer.writerow(flattened)
```

.

```
#JSON DATA FROM SERVER
{
"Mission": "Make Earth Greater Again",
"Objective": "Prove Earth is flat",
"Astronauts": [    {
  "Spaceships": {
    "First": "Katabom",
    "Second": "The Kraken"
  },
  "Name": "Jebeddiah",
  "Gender": "Hopefully male",
  "Age": 35,
  "Prefered colleages": [],
  "Following missions": [
    {
      "Payment_status": "TO BE CONFIRMED"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "Spaceships": {
    "First": "The Kraken",
    "Second": "Minnus I"
  },
  "Name": "Bob",
  "Gender": "Hopefully female",
  "Age": 23,
  "Prefered colleages": [],
  "Following missions": [
    {
      "Payment_status": "TO BE CONFIRMED"
    }
  ]
},
  ]
}
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, the datum you have defined here is not the datum that would be extracted from the server. The datum from the server would be a string. The datum you have in this program is already processed. Now, assuming datum to be:

```
datum = '{"Mission": "Make Earth Greater Again", "Objective": "Prove Earth is flat", "Astronauts": [{"Spaceships": {"First": "Katabom", "Second": "The Kraken"}, "Name": "Jebeddiah", "Gender": "Hopefully male", "Age": 35, "Prefered colleages": [], "Following missions": [{"Payment_status": "TO BE CONFIRMED"}]}, {"Spaceships": {"First": "The Kraken", "Second": "Minnus I"}, "Name": "Bob", "Gender": "Hopefully female", "Age": 23, "Prefered colleages": [], "Following missions": [{"Payment_status": "TO BE CONFIRMED"}]}]}'
```

You don't need the the dpath library. The problem here is that your json flattener doesn't handle embedded lists. Try using the one I've put below.
Assuming that you want a one line csv file,

```
import json
def flattenjson(data, delim, topname=''):
    """JSON flattener that can handle embedded lists and dictionaries"""
    flattened = {}
    def internalflat(int_data, name=topname):
        if type(int_data) is dict:
            for key in int_data:
                internalflat(int_data[key], name + key + delim)
        elif type(int_data) is list:
            i = 1
            for elem in int_data:
                internalflat(elem, name + str(i) + delim)
                i += 1
        else:
            flattened[name[:-len(delim)]] = int_data
    internalflat(data)
    return flattened
#If you don't want mission or objective in csv file
flattened_astronauts = flattenjson(json.loads(datum)["Astronauts"], "__", "Astronaut")
keys = flattened_astronauts.keys().sort()
writer = csv.DictWriter(OD, keys ,restval='Null', delimiter=",", quotechar="\"", quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL, dialect= "excel")
writer.writerow(flattened_astronauts)
```

Comment: After few tries I only get the same error:
    flattened_astronauts = flattenjson({json.loads(datum)["Astronauts"]})
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Basically "Astronauts" is not coded as a dictionary and does not change in that function......

Comment: My bad. Just edited the function to better suit your request and removed the curly braces (they weren't required. Output was already a dictionary.)

Comment: Works! Thank you so much!
The problem now is that the number of astronauts depends on the datum. Therefore headers are produced anytime the number change (function: writer.writeheader() ). Is there any way to set fix headers (the maximum number of astronauts in data is 25) and write the csv file according to this?

Comment: The number of headers will also change based on the number of preferred colleagues, number of spaceships and number of following missions. If you have an idea of the maximum for these, you could initialize a dictionary which would have the maximum number for each with their corresponding values being set to empty. You could then do dict_name.update(json.loads(datum)["Astronauts"]) to update the dictionary before flattening it.

Comment: Indeed. Worked perfectly! Thank you very much!